# Xcode 10 - Getting unit test log files

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10

After running unit tests, I used to find two files in the Tests folder for the Derived Data of Xcode - StandardOutputAndStandardError.txt and TestSummaries.plist files. However, in Xcode 10 I'm unable to find these files. How can I get the test logs in Xcode 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StandardOutputAndStandardError.txt file, you are looking for, is now located in:

```
Derived data
  \your project folder
    \Logs\Test
      \.xcresult file
        \Diagnostics
          \<YourAppNameUITests folder>
            \<YourAppNameUITests folder>
```

again and there it is.

For `<YourAppNameUITests folder>` there is also a folder with log from simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Mine is living under `/private/var/folders`, so it's a temp location.

You can also right-click the failed test in Xcode and `Reveal Diagnostics in Finder`.

Since we run multiple simulator instances at a time on CI, I usually do `grep -R "test name" -l` to know in which files my test failed and then check the `StandardOutputAndStandardError.txt` of that simulator folder.