# Xcode unit testing session exited error while running the unit test cases

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, cocoa-touch, xctest

I am executing the unit test cases using `XCTest` but the test cases are failed without running the method call.
The below error is displayed in the test log.

> Test session exited(45) without completing.

**Below are the log file contents.**

```
10:13:51.477 Xcode[27399:424996] <IDETestOperationCoordinator: 0x7fec86f3a2d0>: parseConsoleOutputFromOriginalOutput: called, 78 bytes written out to StandardOutputAndStandardError
10:13:51.581 Xcode[27399:463189] Lost connection to the test daemon.
10:13:51.581 Xcode[27399:462510] Closing socket 69 to testmanagerd for Sim iPhone 5
10:13:51.582 Xcode[27399:462503] Closing socket 58 to testmanagerd for Sim iPhone 5
10:13:51.585 Xcode[27399:424996] Got death notice for pid 31596, removing from SimulatorSessionMap
10:13:51.585 Xcode[27399:424996] Checking to see if pid 31476 is valid: kill(pid, 0) = 0 (YES, it's still running)
10:13:51.585 Xcode[27399:424996] <IDETestOperationCoordinator: 0x7fec86f3a2d0>: parseConsoleOutputFromOriginalOutput: called, 0 bytes written out to StandardOutputAndStandardError
10:13:51.585 Xcode[27399:424996] <IDETestOperationCoordinator: 0x7fec86f3a2d0> is flushing delegate queue, count: 1
10:13:51.592 Xcode[27399:424996] Launch session LaunchSessionClaim_0x7fec86ee5630 relinquised claim on simulator 8678C2A5-960D-4E64-A1CC-9F485D7A1DFC
10:13:51.592 Xcode[27399:424996] Launch session LaunchSessionClaim_0x7fec86ee5630 relinquised claim on simulator 8678C2A5-960D-4E64-A1CC-9F485D7A1DFC
10:13:51.840 Xcode[27399:424996] <IDETestOperationCoordinator: 0x7fec86f3a2d0> finished receiving data from <IDEConsoleAdaptor: 0x7fec86a9fe30 'target' stdin: (null) 0 stdout: (null) 0 stderr: (null) 0>
10:13:51.840 Xcode[27399:424996] <IDETestOperationCoordinator: 0x7fec86f3a2d0>: _considerFlushingDelegateBlockQueue - nothing to flush
10:13:53.785 Xcode[27399:424996] Test operation failure: Test session exited(45) without completing.
10:13:53.785 Xcode[27399:424996] _finishWithError:Error Domain=IDETestOperationsObserverErrorDomain Code=5 "Test session exited(45) without completing." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Test session exited(45) without completing.}
```

Need to know the reason for this error.

Comment: More info is needed to be able to help you

Comment: The test target is giving the error when the test case is started executing, the log doesn't have any other information apart from this

Comment: It may be helpfull to see the actual test case you are trying to run

Comment: Post the `StandardOutputAndStandardError.txt` file so we can debug this faster - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52520540/xcode-10-getting-unit-test-log-files/53061702#53061702