# Verify flaky UI tests using paraller run and xcodebuild

Tags: swift, xcode, xctest, xcodebuild

I have problems with the flakiness of some of my UI tests. I want to be able to run one particular test multiple times in multiple simulators. The idea is to apply this solution for localhost and then for CI servers.

A perfect solution would be if there is any option that I can mark some test in my PR as `flaky` and then during `xcodebuild test` run them without explicitly specify their name.

I know that there is an option to run tests in parallel but I want to run one test multiple times on copies of a simulator, not distribute tests between them. It should be simpler, I guess.

I found [Can I run an XCTest suite multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31195465/can-i-run-an-xctest-suite-multiple-times) topic where described is how to use `measureBlock` to run continuous tests, but I'm not sure how to specify the number of runs. 
My background is C# where I have access just to `Repeat(x)` and case `Category` which I can specify during a test run. I'm looking for something similar.

Mark test category as `Flaky`-> apply attribute `Retry(10)` -> use command tool to run all tests with `Flaky` category

Looking for some idea what can I do to implement this kind of solution for my iOS tests.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to the question of re-running flaky UI tests is **no**, XCTest & xcodebuild do not support this option. So it is not possible natively.

The longer answer is - **yes**, it is possible, just not easy to implement.

***You will need:***

1. a CI environment, which will run the `xcodebuild` command with your full set of tests
2. python script to get failing tests out of your tests results (or other such language)
3. administration access to your CI runner (or R/W access at least)

***How to do it?***

Your tests will run (and some will fail in the process) in the first `xcodebuild test...`. You will let these finish and you will parse (with a script, which was written by you) those tests, that failed. You can get this info from e.g. `StandardOutputAndError.txt` file ([how do you find it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52520540/xcode-10-getting-unit-test-log-files/53061702#53061702)), thats why you'll need full access to your CI runner.

After your script parses failing tests from the results file, you can construct new `xcodebuild` command withing that script, which would run only the tests, that were parsed, because they failed. The new `xcodebuild` would use `only-testing:` flags (yes, you can have multiple in one `xcodebuild`) to specify the test, it should run ([how to use these flags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39427263/how-to-use-xcodebuild-with-only-testing-and-skip-testing-flag)).

After this, your new, constructed `xcodebuild` command would be returned to the CI environment and executed there. I was dealing with something similar (constructing `xcodebuild` within python script to only run tests according to changes in iOS project and executing it in CI) and [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56429393/pipeline-is-not-failing-when-fail-occurs-inside-python-script) should help you with the execution and CI environment.

To sum this: **no**, there is not native support of this but **yes** it can be done, if you are brave enough :-)

Hope, this helped.

**E:** oh and no - you cannot (and should not) use `measureBlock` for this. These are meant for performance tests and have no such functionality as rerunning failing tests.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Actually I'm looking for best option to multirun one test. I know test name. I just need to run it multiple times on CI. Should I just run `xcodebuild` multiple times in loop or there is other option?

Comment: Hi @Emil, sorry for the late answer - no there is no other option how to multirun one test, other than looping the `xcodebuild` in the CI environment. If you were to do so, I would recommend writing a script in e.g. Python/Shell with input parameter being the test name (names) and multiruning it from within the script, since having loops directly in the CI `script:` (Gitlab) is pain in the *** to maintain and set.

Answer (score 0):

It's now possible, if you migrate your test suite into a test plan (Xcode usually suggests doing it automatically, but [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/organizing-tests-to-improve-feedback)'s a guide from Apple.)

Test plan configuration has "Test Repetition Mode" with options:

- "Until Failure" (repeated until the tests fail)
- "Retry on Failure" (repeated until they pass)
- "Up Until Maximum Repetitions" (run a set number of times)
- "None" (tests are run once)